# Do we have $\alpha^{-1}\widetilde B=\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec}B}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\alpha:\operatorname{Spec}B\to\operatorname{Spec}A$ be a morphism of schemes associated to $f:A\to B$, then we have an $\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec}A}$-module $\widetilde B$.

Do we have $\alpha^{-1}\widetilde B=\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec}B}$?

If $f$ is surjective, do we have $\alpha^{-1}\widetilde B=\mathcal O_{\operatorname{Spec}B}$?

Comment: This is not even a sheaf of modules on $B$.

Comment: If $A=k$, every inverse image w.r.t. $\alpha$ is a locally constant sheaf.